# How i can override Accessibility className for android.widget.TextView

Tags: java, android, accessibility

I want to "talkback" anounces standart TextView as button.
i tried to use this way

```
public class AccessibilityDelegateButton extends AccessibilityDelegateCompat {
    private CharSequence  className;
    public AccessibilityDelegateButton(CharSequence className) {
        super();
        this.className =className;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host,event);
        event.setClassName(className);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host,info);
        info.setClassName(className);
    }
}
```

and activity:

```
    TextView finishButton= new TextView(this);
    ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(finishButton, new AccessibilityDelegateButton(Button.class.getName()));
```

but it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAccessibilityDelegate(android.view.View.AccessibilityDelegate))

> On platform versions prior to API 23, delegate methods on views in the android.widget.* package are called before host methods. This prevents certain properties such as class name from being modified
>
> Starting in API 23, delegate methods are called after host methods, which all properties to be modified without being overwritten by the host class.

And that should be the same for AccessibilityDelegateCompat according to the [note](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat.html)

Are you on API < 23 maybe?
In that case you have to set the class name in `onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo` method of `View.AccessibilityDelegateCompat`